# Can you tell me how to reduce flag size in the left view of textfield in the kizitonwose/CountryPickerView(github)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

the link of the repository is following-
https://github.com/kizitonwose/CountryPickerView

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the size of flag in the datasource method :

```
func cellImageViewSize(in countryPickerView: CountryPickerView) -> CGSize
```

Comment: This function actually reduces the size of the flag but not in the text field where i want it reduces the size of the flag at the table view.

Answer (score 0):

```
func cellImageViewSize(in countryPickerView: CountryPickerView) -> CGSize { 
    return CGSize(width: 20, height: 20) // put any value you want
}
```

Comment: This function actually reduces the size of the flag but not in the text field where i want it reduces the size of the flag at the table view.